# How to add laravel customize boot function

Tags: php, laravel

I want to make boot function for my **app preview**, for that I have plan to add new variable to `.env` file and let's name it `APP_Mode` so I want to say:

> If `APP_Mode=preview` prevent all actions and redirect back with
>   `xxxxxx` text as flash session message.

#### The point

The point of this boot action that I try to achieve is to not let users change any of my preview site settings like store/delete/update etc.

#### Question

**Is that possible? How?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, might be worth considering if Laravel's [maintenance mode](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/configuration#maintenance-mode) might work for you - you can whitelist the IP addresses that are able to access the site, and it will appear down for everyone else.

If that's not going to do the trick, you'll probably be best to create your own middleware - it will likely be similar to the `CheckForMaintenanceMode` middleware that Laravel ships with. In the `handle` method you can check for the configuration option to see if you're in preview mode or not, and then decide how to handle the request.

If you're using "RESTful" routing like Laravel recommends - that is, GET requests are idempotent and don't change anything, and only POST/PUT/DELETE requests make changes - your middleware can simply return a HTTP 403 response (forbidden) if your preview mode is enabled and the request method isn't GET.

A very simple implementation (you'll likely need to tweak) to get you started would be something like this:

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    if (config('app.mode') === 'preview' && $request->method() !== 'GET') {
        abort(403);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Just in regard to using `config('app.mode')` instead of something `env('APP_MODE')` is that you shouldn't be using the `env` helper outside of the configuration files - otherwise you can't take advantage of Laravel's config caching. So add another config option in the `config/app.php` file that you can use to check the mode the app is in.